# Slow performance of ST_CONTAINS on MySQL 5.7

Tags: performance, mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and I have two tables, one containing the geographies of every census block group in the US, for a total of 223,325 rows.

I have another table containing approximately 400 custom geographies. For a given custom geography, I want to retrieve a list of all census block groups that reside within it.

However, the query seems to be taking far too long (well over 30 minutes before I had to cancel it)

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    geo_bg.OGR_FID
FROM
    geo_custom
        JOIN
    geo_bg ON st_contains(geo_custom.shape, geo_bg.shape)
WHERE
    geo_custom.OGR_FID = 213;
```

And the output from EXPLAIN is

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geo_custom | NULL       | const | OGR_FID,SHAPE | OGR_FID | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geo_bg     | NULL       | range | SHAPE         | SHAPE   | 34      | NULL  | 9952 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

I have a spatial key on the `shape` column in both `geo_bg` and `geo_custom`

Is there something obvious I'm missing, or is this type of query very expensive and going to take a long time no matter what?